# Show that $X_{n} \to X-$a.s. when $E(\sup \xi_{n}^{+})< \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

Let $X_{n}, n \in \mathbb N_{0}$ be a submartingale where $\sup X_{n} < \infty$. Further, let $\xi_{n}=X_{n}-X_{n-1}$ where $E(\sup \xi_{n}^{+})< \infty$.

Show that $X_{n}-$a.s converges.

This is clearly a case for the martingale convergence theorem, i.e. I need to show that $\sup E(X_{n}^{+})< \infty$

My idea: Since $X_{n}$ is a submartingale, we know that $E(X_{n+1})\geq E(X_{n})\Rightarrow E(X_{n+1}-X_{n})\geq 0$ and from $\sup_{n}X_{n}< \infty$ we know that for an $N \in \mathbb N$ large enough: for all $n \geq N$: $\xi_{n}^{+}=0$

Hence $E(\sup \xi_{n}^{+})=E(\sup\limits_{1\leq n < N} \xi_{n}^{+})$ and

$\sup E(X_{n}-X_{n-1})\leq E(\sup \xi_{n}^{+})$

I do not know how to use these facts to show that $\sup E(X_{n}^{+})< \infty$, any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578497/submartingale-convergence-durrett-5-3-1 . Your statement that there is an $N$ large enough that $\xi_n^+ = 0$ for all $n \geq N$ is not true.